# Hide the folder and navigation vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to hide the folder and it should not be found when i click show hidden file at navigation.
I use this code to hide the file

```
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(FilePath, IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you mark something `IO.FileAttributes.Hidden` or even as `IO.FileAttributes.System`, they will still be visible after a couple checkbox clicks.  The only way to really hide something would be like in stenography, truecrypt, etc.